# Whether current character rendered width depends from previous character in Android

Tags: android, rendering, character

I have a question about one android text rendering detail:
Whether current character rendered width depends from previos character in android text renderer (for example in textview)?

For example if char 'x' have width equals `x_w` and 'y' - `y_w`, will string "xy" always have with equals

```
x_w + y_w
```

?

Some more details:
The point is that I should measure strings as quiсk as possible. I want to measure once each letter (character) from text using Paint.getTextWidths(...) and then jsut use work with characters width.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the font.  It's not something I would assume, if you want the width of a string, measure the full string.

If you absolutely need that, use a monospace font.

Comment: The point is that I should measure strings as quiсk as possible. I want to measure once each letter (character) from text using Paint.getTextWidths(...) and then jsut use work with characters width.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work very well, unless you're using a monospace font (which tend to look poor).